# Mysql how to use SUM and COUNT in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the query below, which is supposed to get all the **"record"** fields from a mysql table called **users**. The record field's values must be bigger than 0 for it to count. and the query only returns true if 3 or more records found (where record > 0)

The query below makes sense to me, but its returning the following PHP error : **Operand should contain 2 column(s)**

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE (

    SELECT COUNT(record) AS record,

    SUM(CASE WHEN record > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

    FROM users

) >= 3

";
```

Can SUM and COUNT not be used in the same query? I've used them simultaneously in the past with no problems.

Any help would be great thank

**EDIT ---------------------**

```
Table : users 
--------------
id       value
--------------
 1        1
 2        1
 3        1
 4        0
 5        0
 6        -1
 7        -10
 8        0
```

I'd like to only return a result if the **value** field in the table above is bigger than 0. But I also only want to return a result if the total number of values found in the table (where value > 0) are 3 or more.

Comment: I have not upgraded, still on the previous version. It works fine :). the only thing not working is the SUM part of the query

Comment: If theres a better way to write the query, I'm open to it

Comment: Count and Sum can definitely be used in the same query. You are getting the error because your WHERE clause is trying to compare a two-column result to a single value (>=3). What you probably need here is a join, but I'm unclear what you are really trying to do. Please post a sampling of your data, including all columns, and I can get it for you.

Comment: I think the best answer is by @user3783243. I just wanted to use SUM to return how many values are found in the database as a solid number, rather than going through foreach loops in the php code.

Comment: Yes @user3783243 your query does it best! thanks a lot. Really helpful. Is there a way to return the number of counted records for the query without doing a foreach look in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `count` function to count, a `where` to limit the data, and the `having` function to check that you have the number of records you want.

```
select count(*) as counted 
from users 
where record > 0 
having counted > 3
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29ed41e/1

With the above query your PHP will have the results as the first index, or `counted` depending on how you fetch. You don't need to loop the fetch because there will only be 1 row returned.

Roughly:

```
$row = $query->fetch();
return $row['counted'];
```

The number of rows will be 1 so you don't want to count the number of rows, you want the actual returned value.

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Great solution. So I could just use something like `return $query->num_rows();` to get the total count?

Comment: No, there will only be 1 row returned. Fetch the row and return the value it has.